# Merge two dictionaries on date keys

Tags: python, date, merge, ordereddictionary

Suppose you have two (ordered) dicts that map from a (string) date to a decimal number, as below:

```
adata = OrderedDict(
    [('2014-01-06', Decimal('14560.810')), 
     ('2014-01-13', Decimal('17867.040')), 
     ('2013-12-30', Decimal('8941.440')), 
     ('2014-02-10', Decimal('17737.630')), 
     ('2014-02-03', Decimal('14450.870')), 
     ('2014-01-20', Decimal('15595.400')),
     ('2014-02-24', Decimal('6290.760')), 
     ('2014-01-27', Decimal('14619.390'))]) 

bdata=  OrderedDict(
    [('2013-01-27', Decimal('12173.170')), 
     ('2012-12-31', Decimal('14447.010')),  
     ('2014-02-24', Decimal('14861.870')),  
     ('2014-02-27', Decimal('861.870'))])
```

How could you merge `adata` with `bdata` according to the following rules:

1. Merge by month and day, not year.
2. If a key in `adata` is present in `bdata` assign the value of `bdata[key]` at the 2nd position, otherwise assign the value 0 there.
3. Return this, but ordered by date.
4. `Decimal`s can be replaced with floats.

I'd expect this output:

```
cdata =  OrderedDict(
    [('2013-12-30', (Decimal('8941.440'), 0)),
     ('2012-12-31', (0, Decimal('14447.010'))),          
     ('2014-01-06', (Decimal('14560.810'), 0)),
     ('2014-01-13', (Decimal('17867.040'), 0)), 
     ('2014-01-20', (Decimal('15595.400'), 0)),
     ('2014-01-27', (Decimal('14619.390'), Decimal('12173.170'))), 
     ('2014-02-03', (Decimal('14450.870'), 0)), 
     ('2014-02-10', (Decimal('17737.630'), 0)), 
     ('2014-02-24', (Decimal('6290.760'), Decimal('14861.870'))),
     ('2014-02-27', (0, Decimal('861.870'))) ])
```

I tried the following, but I didn't get the output I wanted.

```
cdata = OrderedDict()
for key in adata.keys() + bdata.keys():
if not cdata.has_key(key):
    try:
        val_b = adata[key]
    except KeyError:
        val_b = 0
    try:
        val_c = bdata[key]
    except KeyError:
        val_c = 0
    cdata[key] = (val_b, val_c)
```

Comment: What output DID you get?

Comment: Cuz I get this `{'2014-01-06': (Decimal('14560.810'), 0),
 '2014-01-13': (Decimal('17867.040'), 0),
 '2013-12-30': (Decimal('8941.440'), 0),
 '2014-02-10': (Decimal('17737.630'), 0),
 '2014-02-03': (Decimal('14450.870'), 0),
 '2014-01-20': (Decimal('15595.400'), 0),
 '2014-02-24': (Decimal('6290.760'), Decimal('14861.870')),
 '2014-01-27': (Decimal('14619.390'), 0),
 '2013-01-27': (0, Decimal('12173.170')),
 '2012-12-31': (0, Decimal('14447.010')),
 '2014-02-27': (0, Decimal('861.870'))}` which appears to be correct (unsorted), accepting that you excluded one of your inputs from the output.

Comment: Yes That may be I forget , But it should be in sorted by key date. Could you please share your code here. I will check and let you know. See my edits in cdata

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this at the end:

`cdata = OrderedDict([(key, cdata[key]) for key in sorted(cdata)])`

It will sort your merged dictionary by the date string.

Comment: How to merge those dictionary?

Comment: Your merging code working fine as far as I can tell. I tested it. The output just isn't sorted

Answer (score 0):

To have it properly sorted only by month and day, you will need a custom comparator:

```
month_day = lambda x: tuple(map(int,x[-5:].split('-')))

def month_day_cmp(a,b):
    a = month_day(a)
    b = month_day(b)
    def cmp(a,b,index):
        if index > 1: return 0
        if a[index] > b[index]:
            return 1
        elif a[index] < b[index]:
            return -1
        else:
            return cmp(a,b,index+1)
    return cmp(a, b, 0)


for k,v in OrderedDict(sorted(cdata.items(),cmp=month_day_cmp, key=lambda x: x[0])).items():
    print '{} -> {}'.format(k,v)
```

It's not completely clear from the question how the `cdata` keys are defined. 
For example, if you have two dates with equal month and day but different year - which year do we use in the key? If that is important you will need more code.